# CipherInputStream how to turn on/off the cipher for different bytes you are reading

Tags: java, encryption

I am trying to read a file that has some the data encrypted and some not encrypted.
The start of each message has an *unencrypted header* that contains the byte size of the encrypted message that follows.

My class to read just extends [FileInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) and I override the read operation.
When I create my stream class, I pass in the cipher into the constructor.

In my read(), I need to be able to turn the cipher on/off for different bits in the file buffer.
Is there any way to turn on/off the cipher when performing a read?

Thank you

Comment: No, you can't, but even if you could, it would bytes or blocks and certainly not *bits*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do this. You'd have to split the data.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a wrapper `FileInputStream` class that reads the file and parses it in order to know which parts need to be decrypted and which don't. That class then uses a separate deciphering stream to decrypt the parts that need decrypting. The parts that don't need decrypting are just returned (byte by byte) as is to the reader client of the class.